# ios pass through delegate

Tags: ios, delegation

I have a qusetion regarding how to handle delegates in nested views. Say that I have a UITableView which I want to implement in class B (UIVIew), which is implemented in ViewController (Class A). But I want class A to handle the delegation of the UITableView, is there a way to "pass-through" the delegation methods to AVOID something like this:

http://wireit.dk/stackOverflow/screen1.png

Hope you can help! :D cheers

Comment: I don't think so. You would have one class implement the `UITableViewDelegate`, implement the methods and call the delegate's delegate's methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're actually trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want to have a controller act as a proxy that passes the delegate method calls onto the actual implementing class, which is definitely do-able with a lot less code.

Comment: Isn't `self.myClassBInstance.tableView.delegate = self` in `Class A` sufficient?

Comment: Well, I guess Ian is right, I just would like to have delegate methods for class B (CustomView), which is "more" visible to the viewController. This is rather than having a tableview in CustomView and then having to figure out that I have to access the tableview instance though the CustomView instance. (I guess its, so that that I get a bigger sense of decoupling, so that if I have to reuse the CustomView at some point, I done have to worry about all subclasses and their delegates, I should just implement CustomViewDelegates, and then the compiler would tell me if I'm missing something)